# SELECT statement to convert columns into rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

We have a result set that has one row with four columns:

```
value1, value2, value3, value4
```

How can we turn it into a result set that has four rows with one column:

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are using SQL 2005 or later you can use UNPIVOT

```
SELECT value
FROM (SELECT a, b, c, d FROM myTable) as x
UNPIVOT (value FOR vx IN (a,b,c,d)) as p
```

See also [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) on TechNet

Comment: Give this a read. This should explain to you what you are looking for with Pivot/Unpivot: 
http://blog.devart.com/is-unpivot-the-best-way-for-converting-columns-into-rows.html

Answer (score 2):

If the columns are known:

```
SELECT Value FROM(
    SELECT Value = value1
    FROM dbo.TableName
    UNON ALL
    SELECT Value = value2
    FROM dbo.TableName
    UNON ALL
    SELECT Value = value3
    FROM dbo.TableName
    UNON ALL
    SELECT Value = value4
    FROM dbo.TableName
) X
ORDER BY VALUE -- in case you want that
```

Comment: Is using `UNPIVOT` an alternative approach?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to UNPIVOT data would be to use CROSS APPLY:

```
select value
from (Your select statement) as x
cross apply
( 
  select 'value1', value1 union all
  select 'value2', value2 union all
  select 'value3', value3 union all
  select 'value4', value4
) c (ColumnName, value);
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9533f/1)